# How to remove keys in vars() dict

Tags: python

I want to retrieve a dictionary of different objects and for that I used `vars ()` (or `__dic__`).
Problem is, I am not interested in all the data, I would like to remove some of it but I cannot manage it without getting an error.

My view: (see dic_registre[heros])

```
def chapitre(request, aventure_id, chapitre_id, session_nom_groupe, tour=0):
    # Les variables indispensables:
    aventure = Aventure.objects.get(id=aventure_id)
    chapitre = Chapitre.objects.get(id=chapitre_id)
    session = Session.objects.get(nom_groupe=session_nom_groupe)
    liste_heros = session.heros.all()

    # Vérification du cache ou création:                        --> Reste à ajouter les archives!
    registre = cache.get('registre_' + session.nom_groupe)
    if registre == None:
        dic_registre = {}
        liste_aventures = list(aventure.donnees.all())
        liste_aventures.append(aventure)
        objets_q = [Q(aventure=x) for x in liste_aventures]
        elements_enfants = Element.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, objets_q)).select_subclasses() 
        for enfant in elements_enfants:
            if not isinstance(enfant, (Chapitre, Situation, Heros)):
                dic_registre[enfant.nom] = enfant.to_registre()
        **for heros in liste_heros:
            dic_registre[heros] = heros.to_registre()**
        registre = cache.set('registre_' + session.nom_groupe, dic_registre, 10)
    
    # Création des inventaires:
    if tour == 0:
        for heros in liste_heros:
            inventaire = Inventaire.objects.create(heros=heros, session=session, bourse=100)

    return render(request, 'aventures/chapitre.html', locals())
```

my def in the model Element, parent of Heros:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    nom = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    aventure = models.ForeignKey(Aventure, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    accessible = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Ce champs définit si l\'on peut accéder par défaut à l\'élément ou non.')
    description = models.TextField('Description de l\'élément en quelques mots', blank=True, null=True, max_length=250, help_text='250 caractères maximum.')
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    def __str__(self):        
        return self.genre

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "éléments"
    
    # Pour créer le registre à partir des éléments de base:
    def to_registre(self):
        if isinstance(self, Heros):
            dic = vars(self)
            a_enlever = ('_state', 'id', 'genre', 'nom', 'description', 'element_ptr_id', 'user_id', 'aventure_id' )
            for key in a_enlever:
                if key in dic:
                    del dic[key]
            
        else:
            dic = {'accessible': [self.accessible,]}
        return dic
```

The error is as follows:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'

I tried with `.pop()` and got the same error.

Do you know where the problem could come from?

Thx!

edit, i'm not sure about what is the full stack trace, sorry:

```
aventure    <Aventure: La conquête du dragon>
aventure_id     4
chapitre    <Chapitre: 1.Préparatifs avant de partir>
chapitre_id     4
dic_registre    {'Intimider': {'accessible': [True]}}
elements_enfants    <InheritanceQuerySet [<Action: Intimider>, <Chapitre: 1.Préparatifs avant de partir>, <Chapitre: 2.Le marais>, <Chapitre: 3.Le passage sous la montagne>]>
enfant  <Chapitre: 3.Le passage sous la montagne>
heros   Error in formatting: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
liste_aventures     [<Aventure: Pack : Actions simples>, <Aventure: La conquête du dragon>]
liste_heros     Error in formatting: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
objets_q    [<Q: (AND: ('aventure', <Aventure: Pack : Actions simples>))>,
 <Q: (AND: ('aventure', <Aventure: La conquête du dragon>))>]
registre    None
request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/aventures/4/4/dfrg/'>
session     <Session: dfrg>
session_nom_groupe  'dfrg'
tour    0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\site_django\aventures\views.py", line 81, in chapitre
    dic_registre[heros] = heros.to_registre()
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 534, in __hash__
    if self.pk is None:
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 568, in _get_pk_val
    return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 137, in __get__
    val = self._check_parent_chain(instance)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 153, in _check_parent_chain
    return getattr(instance, link_field.attname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
[26/Jul/2020 14:43:31] "GET /aventures/4/4/dfrg/ HTTP/1.1" 500 98404
[26/Jul/2020 14:43:31] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/img/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[26/Jul/2020 14:43:31] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[26/Jul/2020 14:43:31] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 200 41
[26/Jul/2020 14:43:31] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 14984
[26/Jul/2020 14:43:31] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/img/djdt_vertical.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

---

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60201)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nicou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\nicou\Desktop\Virtuel\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\nicou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
```

---

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made a second dictionary by retrieving everything that i need:

```
def to_registre(self):
    if isinstance(self, Heros):
        dic_complet = vars(self)
        a_enlever = ('_state', 'id', 'genre', 'nom', 'description', 'element_ptr_id', 'user_id', 'aventure_id' )
        dic = {'chapitre': 1, 'situation': 1}
        for key, value in dic_complet.items():
            if not key in a_enlever:
                dic[key] = [value,]
    else:
        dic = {'accessible': [self.accessible,]}
    return dic
```

But I would still be curious to know what is wrong with my first method ...